# Algorithm for sorting a list in python does not work properly

Tags: python

I am using the following function in order to sort a list in an increasing order. However, while my function works for lists such as: `[1,5,6,9,3]` or `[56,43,16,97,45]`, it does not work for lists of the form: `[20,10,1,3,50]`.

In such cases, the computer seems to consider that 3>20 and 3>10 and 3 ends up right before 50 (second to last) in the "sorted" list I get. More precisely the result I get is: `[1,10,20,3,50]`.

Here is my code:

```
def function_sort(L):

    for j in range(len(L)):
        min=j
        for i in range(j+1,len(L)):
           if L[i]<L[min]:
              min = i

        if(min != j):
            L[j],L[min] = L[min],L[j]

            print L
    return L
```

Could anyone please explain me what is going on?

Comment: Why don't you use the in built `.sort()` method?

Comment: @Scironic: To me, this sounds like a pretty reasonable programming exercise.

Comment: Can't say I understand the downvotes given that this is an on-topic, reasonable and clearly formulated question.

Comment: Please provide a working sample including the input. It could be that your lists are actually of strings not integers.

Comment: @NPE agree on the downvotes, in terms of this being a programming exercise - if it is then fine. If it's not then Aribas is missing a fairly obvious tool. Either way if it is an exercise I think that should be stated.

Comment: I gave it a run and it totally works like intendent (at least if you hand over a list of ints)

Comment: @Scironic This is not some kind of exercise. I am new in python and I am simply trying to find my way around. I am aware of the .sort function, but in any case I tried to code the selection sort in order to practice. I thought we were allowed to ask all sorts of questions in this site (even really elementary ones) as long as they are well-stated and it appears we have worked on them. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Aribas, by the way you've put it you have used it as an exercise to learn (a self-defined one). SO's a unique place when it comes to elementary questions, I don't have an issue with them and am happy to answer, but they will often be downvoted as some see them as easy to research and figure out without SO's help.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like your list consists of strings rather than integers, and you end up getting the elements sorted [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

By way of illustration, consider the following:

```
>>> 10 < 2
False
>>> '10' < '2'
True
```

To fix the issue, convert the elements to integers before sorting:

```
L = map(int, L)
```

P.S. I recommend against using `min` as a variable name since it [shadows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125172/how-bad-is-shadowing-names-defined-in-outer-scopes) the built-in function [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min).

Comment: Or sort with a `key`, e.g. `L.sort(key=int)`