# Confusing variable scope (shadowing variable from outer scope)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I used to program in C, C# and Java. Now I'm using Python for a while but I encountered some problems with understanding variable scope which is quite confusing for me right now. For example:

```
def f1():
    print(spam)   # spam magically come from outer scope. ok...


def f2():
    spam = "bbb"  # assignment shadows variable from outer scope (logical result of f1)
    print(spam)   # printing local spam variable


def f3():
    print(spam)   # ERROR: unresolved reference 'spam'
    spam = "ccc"  # in f1 function everything was fine but adding assignment AFTER
                  # printing (in opposite to f2 function) causes error in line above


def f4():
    print(spam)   # nothing wrong here, assignment line below is commented
    # spam = "ccc"

spam = "aaa"
```

Why on earth functions can reach variables outside their scope?
And why shadowing variable from outer scope is ok but only if we didn't use it before?

Comment: Are you sure you get an 'unresolved reference error' in `f3`? I would expect the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'spam' referenced before assignment` which is rather self-explaining.

Comment: what happens in `f2` is your changing variable `spam` from `aaa` to `bbb`

Comment: @kazemakase  You're right, that error I wrote was from IDE not from runtime

Comment: @MahmutKilic It prints "bbb" since spam is now a local variable

Comment: @kazemakase But it means spam magically changed from "global" variable in f1 to local in f3

Comment: @user3616181 nothing magical about it. See my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python code is compiled to byte code before execution. This means Python can analyze how the function uses variables. A variable is either *global* or *local* in a function but not both and it cannot change.

`spam` is global in `f1` because it is never assigned. `spam` is local in `f2` because it is assigned. The same goes for `f3`. `spam`is local in `f3` because of `spam='ccc'`. With the `print(spam)` statement you try to access the local variable before it was assigned.

You can use `global spam` inside a function to forcefully declare a variable name as global.

Local stays local. Even after deleting a variable in the local namespace Python does not look up the name in the parent scope:

```
spam = 123

def f():
    spam = 42
    print(spam)  # 42
    del spam
    print(spam)  # UnboundLocalError

f()
```

If you want to assign a global variable you need to declare it:

```
spam = 123

def f():
    global spam
    spam = 42
    print(spam)  # 42

f()
print(spam)  # 42
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot that even many people say that python is interpreted right from the script it in fact has compilation phase.

Comment: But why functions can reach outer variables? What's the idea behind this? Because someone had to come to conclusion that it's a desirable behavior

Comment: @user3616181 Because in Python there is no difference between variables, functions, and other objects. You want to be able to call `print` inside your function definition, don't you? `print` is a global object and so is `spam`. `spam` could also be a function that you want to call inside your other function. There is simply no reason not to allow global lookup. I once thought about disabling this feature, but this turned out to be a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31023487/3005167).

Comment: Knowing that "in Python there is no difference between variables, functions, and other objects" the situation is clear. In other languages I used there was a significant difference between functions and variables. You could call function outside your scope but you couldn't use such variables. That's why I was so confused. Thanks for clearing it out.