# make local copy of global variable

Tags: python, scope, copy

I'm probably missing something really obvious, but how do I create a local copy of a global vaiable with the same name?
I have something like:

```py
d = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}

def foo():
    d = d.copy()
    d["four"] = 4
```

I want to create a copy of d in the inner scope that I can modify as I like without affecting the global version. This will complain that d is reference before assignment, which makes perfect sense because it is being interpreted as a local variable. If I declare it global though, this will modify it.

This would be trivial if I didn't mind if it had a different name eg: `d_local = d.copy()`, but that would be a big hassle in this situation and not just a find and replace one either.

If the only solution is to use a new name and deal with the consequences let me know.

Comment: if you are inside a class function you could use `self.d`.

Comment: [Further relevant discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023060/disable-global-variable-lookup-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally using local and global variables with the same name is a really bad practice as it causes confusion. You could use d as an argument, or simply use a different name. However if you really wanted to leave your code structure untouched (which I do not recommend), you could define a function in the global scope that returns a copy of d. As such :

```
d = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}

def copyD():
  return d.copy()

def foo():
  d = copyD()
  d["four"] = 4
```

As pointed out by @rici the function could be defined inside the local scope by using the global keyword :

```
d = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}

def foo():
  def copyD():
    global d
    return d.copy()
  d = copyD()
  d["four"] = 4
```

This code is better, because the copyD function really won't be used anywhere else.

Comment: oof. Tricky, but a clever hack.

Comment: Nice. No need to make a global function. You can use a nested function inside `foo` if you specify `global d` inside the nested function.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to use another identifier if you are doing it this way. A variable can be either local or global but not both ... That's the *whole point of scope*. When you assign to something in a function, it will default to local. But if you make it global, i.e. by using the `global` statement, it will re-assign your global variable, which presumably you don't want (although, it would mutate a *new object* not the one being referenced by your global variable prior to calling the function).

The most reasonable thing here would be to take `d` as an argument. Then simply do `d = d.copy()`

so:

```
d = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}

def foo(d):
    d = d.copy()
    d["four"] = 4

foo(d)
```

> This would be trivial if I didn't mind if it had a different name eg:
>   `d_local = d.copy()`, but that would be a big hassle in this situation
>   and not just a find and replace one either.

That sounds like a *fundamental* problem with your code. Identifiers should not really matter other than to help you understand your own code. If your logic depends on identifiers, that is almost always bad. Read [Keep Data Out of Your Variable Names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) which is yet another excellent tutorial by Ned Batchelder.

Comment: That article really helps! It puts into words and generalized the idea of "don't use twenty variables; use a list"