# Preventing a function from looking up variables outside it

Tags: python, python-3.x, scoping

Consider the following code:

```
def pp():
    print(f'{aa=}')

if __name__ =='__main__':
    aa = 11
    pp()
```

This prints `aa=11`. This means `pp` is getting the value of `aa` from outside `pp`. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023060/disable-global-variable-lookup-in-python

Comment: @Axe319 Yes, it does. Thanks. The second answer there is what I was looking for. I'm not sure why it didn't turn up when I was searching.