# for loop skipping 1st and 2nd element

Tags: python, for-loop, index-error

Since Wednesday, for loop is not working correctly in Python(2.7) in (with windows 10). See screen shot. Its skipping the 1st and somestimes the 2nd element (index 0 and 1). A similar while loop works fine.

[image: Screen shot of simple example. For loop skips index 0 and 1. While loop wrks fine]

Comment: `i` is the element not the index... and post code & errors as text, not images.

Comment: What happened Wednesday?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping Through List Returns Negative Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525168/looping-through-list-returns-negative-index)

Comment: When you do `for i in list` then i becomes an element of the list not an index, so you cannot do `list[i]`

Comment: @tiwo Brain fog?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so if you are using `for` loop you should either go:

```
for i in my_list:
    print i
```

Or:

```
for i, element in enumerate(my_list):
    print my_list[i]
```

In both cases don't call your variable `list` as it is a reserved keyword for actual list.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an answer but hopefully this might explain what is going on

```
>>> l =[1,2,3,4]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for i in l:
...  print "value of i=",str(i), "value of l at index[i]", str(l[i])
... 
value of i= 1 value of l at index[i] 2
value of i= 2 value of l at index[i] 3
value of i= 3 value of l at index[i] 4
value of i= 4 value of l at index[i]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

There is no value available at l[4] as the starting position is l[0] through to l[3]