# Why does python behave this way with variables?

Tags: python

I have been trying to understand why python behaves this way, in the block of code below. I have done my research but couldn't find a good answer so I came here to see if anyone can point me in the right direction or provide a good clarification. 
I understand that it has to do with some old ALGOL principle, but I don't fully understand it.

```
var = 5

def func1():
    print(var)
func1()

def func2():
    var = 8
    print(var)
func2()

def func3():
    print(var)
    var = 8
func3()
```

**The output of this code is as follows:**

5
8
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var' referenced before assignment

I understand why we get the outputs '5' and '8'. But with 'func3()', I was expecting an output of '5'. As it seems, the interpreter thinks that I want to print the local 'var' in the function instead of the global 'var'. So it throws this error.

Or maybe if a variable is defined somewhere inside of the function, then the function will default to the local variable, instead of a global one with the same name.

But why exactly does python behave this way ? I am not complaining, I am just trying to understand something...

How could I use a predefined global variable in a function, then define a local variable with the same name inside of the same function, without changing the value of the global variable ? ( in python of course )

Thanks in advance to everyone here. You are amazing people ! :)

*Edit_1: Thanks every one for the great answers. I totally understand that it is a bad and unpractical idea to use a predefined global variable in a function, then define a local variable with the same name inside of the same function. I was just thinking about it from a theoretical perspective, because I saw it in a college lecture. XD
I can't find a single use case, in which it would be optimal to do that either !*

*Edit_2: I already read the PEP8 and I know that being explicit is better than being implicit. :)
It's true. Otherwise the code will be confusing and lead to bugs. 
That question was just about some useless and impractical college theory that I was trying to understand.*

*Edit_3:
Now I fully understand why it happens and what is going on here. Thanks to [Randall Valenciano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3558900/randall-valenciano) for providing this link to a [blog](https://foreigngods.com/blog/2013/09/14/26/python-exhibits-behavior-similar-to-javascripts-variable-hoisting/) that explains it very well.*

What happens is that the function is interpreted as a whole, and not line by line. So when the function is being interpreted, the variable declarations of any defined variables, are moved to the top of the function. So when we are printing 'var', the function is using the locally declared variable that doesn't have any value assigned to it yet, and then the interpreter complains about it and throws and error.

Thanks to all of you again ! :)
You have been of great help to me ! Now I finally understand what is going on there under the hood.

Comment: Is the same behavior as JS hoisting,a  quick and concise explanation here: https://foreigngods.com/blog/2013/09/14/26/python-exhibits-behavior-similar-to-javascripts-variable-hoisting/

Comment: Yes, the compiler marks it as local if anywhere in the code block it is assigned to. We don't think you can use a global variable then make a local variable with the same name in the same block. Why on Earth would you want to? That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/370357/1639625 But I think this is actually asking a different question.

Comment: You could define `def func3(var=var):`; this will assign the local parameter `var` the value of the global `var`, and all assignments to `var` inside `func3` go to the local variable, but it does so when the function is defined, so the local `var` might not have the current value of the global `var` when the function is called. Again the question: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `var` is defined as a global variable.  In each function when you're only reading the `var` you're accessing the global var, but the moment there's an assigned value to `var` somewhere in the function, python treats *every* `var` within the function as a local variable.  Thus why your last function failed, because `print(var)` (the local varaible) was called before `var = 8` was assigned.

You can read up a bit about more in these threads:
[How bad is shadowing names defined in outer scopes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125172/how-bad-is-shadowing-names-defined-in-outer-scopes)
[Python nonlocal statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement)

The best thing to do is be explicit about your code so it's no longer confusing if you're trying to reference a local, nonlocal or global variable.

In this case, assuming your intention is to keep using the global var, do this:

```
var = 5

def func1():
    print(var)
func1()

def func2():
    global var
    var = 8
    print(var)
func2()

def func3():
    global var
    print(var)
    var = 8  # technically this is not necessary any more var = 8 was already assigned when func2() is called
func3()
```

The output is thus:

```
5
8
8
```

Edit: Thanks to [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga)'s comment - I missed your original question.

> How could I use a predefined global variable in a function, then
>   define a local variable with the same name inside of the same
>   function, without changing the value of the global variable ? ( in
>   python of course )

The short answer is - define the local `var` first like you did in `func2()` and you're good.  The longer answer though is - why would you want to do that? It creates confusion and becomes a headache to track which is when you have variables of the same name in different scope.  A better approach would be name your local var to be `local_var` or something so it's distinctly different and easily traced.

Comment: This changes the global value in `func3`

Comment: Yes, but with his `var = 8` line in `func3()` I'm assuming that's the intention.

Comment: "How could I use a predefined global variable in a function, then define a local variable with the same name inside of the same function, **without changing the value of the global variable ?**"

Comment: Ah I'm completely blind.  Thanks for that.  The answer IMO should be "they shouldn't be doing that", but I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a rule for Python Scope Resolution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

LEGB Rule.

**L, Local** — Names assigned in any way within a function (def or lambda)), and not declared global in that function.

**E, Enclosing-function locals** — Name in the local scope of any and all statically enclosing functions (def or lambda), from inner to outer.

**G, Global (module)** — Names assigned at the top-level of a module file, or by executing a global statement in a def within the file.

**B, Built-in (Python)** — Names preassigned in the built-in names module : open,range,SyntaxError,...

So basically in your question, the scope resolution is "from inside out" and since you aren't using the `global` keyword, the interpreter doesn't know to look outside the local function scope to find that variable `var`. All the interpreter sees is that you are using a variable before declaring and defining it, thus throwing the error. Global variables are often dangerous, and so Python wants to make sure you know you want to use a global variable by forcing you to be explicit about it.

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) for an explanation of the `global` keyword

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already understand what the global variable does. And also the concept of python's scope resolution. :) I was just trying to understand the behavior of python in this particular situation. As to why it went for the local variable instead of the global variable inside of the function. Why didn't it use the local variable only in the lines after definition, and the global variable before. :)