# Variable written within if/else scope is undefined outside

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements

When looping through the contents of a CSV file I am trying to create a start time and an end time;

I know the forms submitted based on the `row['form']` and I log the time of submitting for those forms, I am trying to create a `start` and `end` time so I can later get an average time for the completion of their forms.

```
for row in rows:
    branch = Branch(row['user_id'], row['form'], row['time'])
    if branch.id == row['user_id']:
        if branch.form == 'signup':
            time = {i: {'start': branch.time}}
            print(time)
        elif branch.form == 'submit':
            time = {i: {'end': branch.time}}
            print(time)

        print(time) # line 27
```

The problem with the code snippet above is that for the `print()` **inside** of the conditional statements it works just fine; I get the start time as well as the end time.

But when I try to print it **outside** of the conditional statement it does not work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(time)
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

Now, if I `print` `time` outside of the `for` loop then it gives me the last value; I cannot get any of the previous values.

Comment: What is the value of `branch.form`? Are you sure that it is `signup` or `submit`?

Comment: @JimWright it is the name of the form in a `str`. Yes, `signup` and `submit` are there among the others.

Comment: My point was if it is anything but `signup` and `submit`, then your are not defining `time`.

Comment: @JimWright So it doesn't increment to the dictionary `time` (e.g. `time[i]`)? How would I assign the values then. There are 5 forms, I just need the first and last times.

Comment: Likely, `branch.form` is neither `'signup'` nor `'submit'`. Certainly, `if` and `else` blocks do not have their own scope.

Comment: I agree. Add an `else` at least to define `time` if you are using it for all values of `branch.form`

Comment: So simply add a `else` statemt at the end?

Comment: Yes, add an else statement and set a default time. Maybe `None` would be good for this case?

Comment: If `branch.form` is not equal to `'signup'`, and is also not equal to `'submit'`, **what should the value of `time` be**? In fact, **should the `print` happen**? Nobody else can answer these questions for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "time" variable redefinable and accessible in multiple scopes, you'll need to use the [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) key word. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192290/why-does-python-behave-this-way-with-variables/48192698#48192698).

Hope it helps.