# How to run different code per letter as you type in Python

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

I want to make my python code run a different function as you type, one function assigned per letter.

I would have the code for each letter

```py
def a():
    # The letter A code
def b():
    # The letter B code
```

Then the input (something like this)

```py
letters = input("Input Text:") 
print (letters)
```

And when it prints `letters` it runs the "a" function for a, "b" function for b, and so on.
I'm pretty new to python so any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is an `if-else` statement.

Comment: Do you mean the user will enter a string like , say ur name itself "simon" and when user for each letter in the word you will invoke the function? and when print is invoked do u expect simon to be printed on the screen or just the functions to be executed??

Comment: @Vasyl Please don't recommend `eval` to beginners. OP hasn't mentioned what context this is going to be used in, so you don't know if you can trust the input. As well, please don't post answers in the comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [detect key press in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python)

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran Exactly! Just the functions to be executed...

Comment: Do you mean that the functions will be called in *real-time*? Like as each key is pressed the corresponding function will be called, or after the input is finished to call the function on each letter of it?

Comment: @wjandrea That would be good but I can't figure out how to get it working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume that all the functions for each letter is going to be a in a separate module called `key_functions.py`

In the main program where you are going to process the letters:

```
import key_functions
def print(letter):
    for letter in letters:
         try:
             key_func = getattr(key_functions, letter)
         except:
             raise
         key_func()


letters = input("Input Text:") 
print(letters)
```

NOTE: the print function is something which is going to be visible inside this module only!!

Comment: There's a few problems in this: 1) [A bare `except` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54948581/4518341). Catch the specific exception you're expecting instead, i.e. `AttributeError`. 2) `print` takes a parameter `letter`, but then you iterate over `letters`, which is from the parent scope. [In general you should avoid reusing names from other scopes.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20125172/4518341) 3) [Avoid shadowing builtins like `print`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79198/4518341). In your code, you call `print` in the `except` block, which will probably cause a `RecursionError`.

Comment: yeah i agree with the recursion error.. others are kind of okay..

Comment: @Arun No, the parameter should definitely be fixed. For example, `letters = 0; print('hello')` will error. As well, `except: raise` does practically nothing, but catching `AttributeError` would make sense, and if I were you, I would have it do something like `raise ValueError(f'invalid letter: {letter}')`

Answer (score 0):

```
def a():
    print('a ran')

def b():
    print('b ran')

letters = input("Input Text:") 
print (letters)

for l in list(letters): locals()[l]()
```

The printout if you enter, say `'ababab'` with the quote marks would be:

```
Input Text:'ababab'
ababab
a ran
b ran
a ran
b ran
a ran
b ran
```