# Why and how to resolve shadows argument name from outer scope in class (python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Why and how to resolve shadows argument name from outer scope in class (python) ?

```
from optparse import OptionParser

class Test(object):
   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def _test1(self, some_val):
      print(some_val)

   def main(self, some_val):
      self.test1(some_val)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   parser = OptionParser()
   parser.add_option("-a", "--abcd", dest="abcd", default=None,
                      help="some_val")

   (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
   some_val = options.abcd

   mainobj = Test()
   mainobj.main(some_val)
```

In above code

1. argument `'some_val'` in `'main'` and `'_test'` , displays shadows `'some_val'` from outer scope.
2. at method `'_test'` , displays `'_test'` may be static.

**Pycharm, Python 3.8**

Why those ? And how can I resolve them ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the problem with shadowing names defined in outer scopes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125172/what-is-the-problem-with-shadowing-names-defined-in-outer-scopes)

Answer (score 2):

#### argument 'some_val' in 'main' and '_test' , displays shadows 'some_val' from outer scope.

You have declared a `some_val` variable in you global scope:

```
some_val = options.abcd
```

Since this variable is global, it is normally accessible from anywhere in the module.

But your `Test._test1` and `Test.main` methods define `some_val` arguments which are accessible only from the methods body: they are in the methods local scopes.

This warning simply informs you that the `some_val` parameters are hiding (["shadowing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)) the `some_val` global variable, and that you won't be able to access the global variable from the method body (since `some_val` will refer to the local parameter).

Technically, if you don't need to access the global `some_val` variable from the methods body, it is not a problem.

You can fix this warning by simply giving better names to your variables/parameters, and not reusing same names for global and local variables.

---

#### at method '_test' , displays '_test' may be static

This warning means that, since your `Test1._test` method does not use the `self` argument, it could be declared as static using the [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator (see more details in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod)):

```py
@staticmethod
def _test1(some_val):
    print(some_val)
```

Answer (score 1):

- As others have explained, you have two variables called `some_val` which could technically be visible in the same part of the code; PyCharm is warning you about this because it can be confusing to have two different variables with the same name.

  In this case, the solution is to put the code after `if __name__ == '__main__'` into a function, and only have a call to that function after the `if`; that moves the variables used in that section of the code into a local scope, so they won't be confused with variables elsewhere:

  ```
  def main():
     parser = OptionParser()
     parser.add_option("-a", "--abcd", dest="abcd", default=None,
                        help="some_val")

     (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
     some_val = options.abcd

     mainobj = Test()
     mainobj.main(some_val)

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
  ```

  You could also do this only partially, like this:

  ```
  def get_some_val():
     parser = OptionParser()
     parser.add_option("-a", "--abcd", dest="abcd", default=None,
                        help="some_val")

     (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
     return options.abcd

  if __name__ == "__main__":
     mainobj = Test()
     mainobj.main(get_some_val())
  ```
- The method `_test` makes no use of the `self` parameter.

  If that's what's intended, you can mark it as `@staticmethod` and omit the `self`:

  ```
  @staticmethod
  def _test1(some_val):
      print(some_val)
  ```

  Alternately, expand the method so that it does, in fact, use `self` (which you may have been planning to do in any case).